# Group by & count with Pandas like with SQL?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count

Editing the question, to provide more details in the text form.

So I have DF :

```
print (a)

    Year      City  occurrence
0   1905  New York           1
1   1921  New York           1
2   1922  New York           1
3   1923  New York           1
4   1927  New York           1
5   1927  New York           1
6   1928  New York           1
7   1928  New York           1
8   1932  New York           1
9   1933  New York           1
10  1933  New York           1
11  1934  New York           1
12  1936  New York           1
13  1937  New York           1
14  1938  New York           1
15  1938  New York           1
16  1939  New York           1
17  1940  New York           1
18  1941  New York           1
19  1943  New York           1
20  1947  New York           1
21  1949  New York           1
22  1950  New York           1
23  1951  New York           1
24  1952  New York           1
25  1953  New York           1
26  1954  New York           1
27  1955  New York           1
28  1956  New York           1
29  1956  New York           1
30  1958  New York           1
31  1961  New York           1
32  1962  New York           1
33  1968  New York           1
34  1969  New York           1
35  1970  New York           1
36  1973  New York           1
37  1977  New York           1
38  1978  New York           1
39  1980  New York           1
40  1981  New York           1
41  1982  New York           1
42  1983  New York           1
43  1986  New York           1
44  1986  New York           1
45  1990  New York           1
46  1994  New York           1
47  1995  New York           1
48  1996  New York           1
49  1998  New York           1
50  1999  New York           1
51  2000  New York           1
52  2000  New York           1
53  2003  New York           1
54  2007  New York           1
55  2009  New York           1
56  2011  New York           1
57  2021  New York           1
```

I want to do simple group by & count, and add new column with count. With SQL I would just do simple

```
select Year, City, count(*) from t1 group by 1,2
```

But I'm having trouble to do that.

I tried this:

```
 df['cnt'] = df.groupby(['Year', 'City']).cumcount()+1
```

But I get something like this:

```
4   1927  New York           1
5   1927  New York           2
```

While obviously, I would expect to get only 1 row with value 2.

Any ideas?

Additionally, do I need column "Occurrence", which I added manually. Can I just count without it, like in SQL?

As suggested by @mozway I tried:

```
a['Cnt'] = a.groupby(['Year', 'City'])['occurrence'].sum()
```

But I get the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:10775, in _reindex_for_setitem(value, index)
  10774 try:
> 10775     reindexed_value = value.reindex(index)._values
  10776 except ValueError as err:
  10777     # raised in MultiIndex.from_tuples, see test_insert_error_msmgs

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:4580, in Series.reindex(self, index, **kwargs)
   4572 @doc(
   4573     NDFrame.reindex,  # type: ignore[has-type]
   4574     klass=_shared_doc_kwargs["klass"],
   (...)
   4578 )
   4579 def reindex(self, index=None, **kwargs):
-> 4580     return super().reindex(index=index, **kwargs)

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:4818, in NDFrame.reindex(self, *args, **kwargs)
   4817 # perform the reindex on the axes
-> 4818 return self._reindex_axes(
   4819     axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value, copy
   4820 ).__finalize__(self, method="reindex")

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:4834, in NDFrame._reindex_axes(self, axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value, copy)
   4833 ax = self._get_axis(a)
-> 4834 new_index, indexer = ax.reindex(
   4835     labels, level=level, limit=limit, tolerance=tolerance, method=method
   4836 )
   4838 axis = self._get_axis_number(a)

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py:2533, in MultiIndex.reindex(self, target, method, level, limit, tolerance)
   2532 try:
-> 2533     target = MultiIndex.from_tuples(target)
   2534 except TypeError:
   2535     # not all tuples, see test_constructor_dict_multiindex_reindex_flat

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py:202, in names_compat.<locals>.new_meth(self_or_cls, *args, **kwargs)
    200     kwargs["names"] = kwargs.pop("name")
--> 202 return meth(self_or_cls, *args, **kwargs)

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py:553, in MultiIndex.from_tuples(cls, tuples, sortorder, names)
    551         tuples = np.asarray(tuples._values)
--> 553     arrays = list(lib.tuples_to_object_array(tuples).T)
    554 elif isinstance(tuples, list):

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx:2919, in pandas._libs.lib.tuples_to_object_array()

ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [139], in <module>
----> 1 a['Cnt'] = a.groupby(['Year', 'City'])['occurrence'].sum()

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3612, in DataFrame.__setitem__(self, key, value)
   3609     self._setitem_array([key], value)
   3610 else:
   3611     # set column
-> 3612     self._set_item(key, value)

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3784, in DataFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3774 def _set_item(self, key, value) -> None:
   3775     """
   3776     Add series to DataFrame in specified column.
   3777 
   (...)
   3782     ensure homogeneity.
   3783     """
-> 3784     value = self._sanitize_column(value)
   3786     if (
   3787         key in self.columns
   3788         and value.ndim == 1
   3789         and not is_extension_array_dtype(value)
   3790     ):
   3791         # broadcast across multiple columns if necessary
   3792         if not self.columns.is_unique or isinstance(self.columns, MultiIndex):

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4506, in DataFrame._sanitize_column(self, value)
   4504 # We should never get here with DataFrame value
   4505 if isinstance(value, Series):
-> 4506     return _reindex_for_setitem(value, self.index)
   4508 if is_list_like(value):
   4509     com.require_length_match(value, self.index)

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:10782, in _reindex_for_setitem(value, index)
  10778     if not value.index.is_unique:
  10779         # duplicate axis
  10780         raise err
> 10782     raise TypeError(
  10783         "incompatible index of inserted column with frame index"
  10784     ) from err
  10785 return reindexed_value

TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['Year', 'City'])['Occurrence'].sum()` (or `count` if only 1s)

Comment: Hey @mozway, yeah I was able to do that. But how to add new column with count value?

Comment: `df['Cnt'] = df.groupby(['Year', 'City'])['Occurrence'].sum()`

Comment: @mozway I tried that before, and I always get the error `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`

Comment: then please provide a reproducible example of the error (as **text**!)

Comment: Hey @mozway , I edited the question and added DF and error as a text.

Comment: but I am confused, if you want to aggregate, then of course the output is smaller and has a different index, so it doesn't make sense to store it back into the original dataframe. Maybe you want `df.groupby(['Year', 'City'])['occurrence'].transform('sum')`

Comment: Yeah, you are right @mozway . I want a new df, where I will 1 row as per grouped cols (city, year). 
How I can get that? That's why I gave SQL example. 

If you look at the question above you can see that I get 2 rows (e.g. year 1927), and I would expect to get 1 row with count 2. 

How can I create new DF to get following columns: year, city, count?

Thanks!

Comment: Then no assignment required ;)

Comment: But how to get new DF in a way, like I explained in the previous comment above?

Comment: Hey @mozway , in the end all I wanted to do is this `new = ny.groupby(['Year','City'])['occurrence'].agg('count').reset_index()` which is an equivalent of the SQL example I shared. Thanks for the help!

Comment: great! Glad you got it like you want